# Object of class App\city_cost could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel helpers function. I am passing an argument to it that contains a value which I want to use to update the user table a field cold totcosty. But Everytime it is showing me this error.
This is the helper function

```
 Class Helper{
 public static function cost($citycos)
{

           $user = new User();

            $user->totcosty  += $citycos;
            $user->update();
}
```

}

This is where I passed the value

```
public function store(Storecit $request)
{
$citycos->cost=$request->input('city_cost');
    $citycos->save();
    Helper::cost($citycos);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the cost as argument, not the object

```
$test = Helper::cost($citycoss->cost);
```

Comment: the 'cost' method return nothing, if you want to get something in $test, your method must return it